# sympy units conversion

Tags: units-of-measurement, sympy

I have a little problem with units in sympy.
If i do following expression:

```
import sympy.physics.units as u
print u.kg + u.kg
```

I get as result:

```
2*kg
```

which is not what I want, I would like to have only kg. Whats the problem?

//edit
I saw that there are people working on this problem in https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/1389 does anyone know more about this?

Comment: Your best bet is to create a GitHub account if you don't already have one and click "watch" at the top of the page. That will send you an email any time some progress is made on that pull request.

Answer (score 5):

A kilogram plus a kilogram is two kilograms. I don't understand why you want just kg again.